# Why are finding elements most efficient in arrays in c++?

Tags: c++, set, find

I need a fast STL container for finding if an element exists in it, so I tested arrays, vectors, sets, and unordered sets. I thought that sets were optimized for finding elements, because of unique and ordered values, but the fastest for 10 million iterations are:
arrays (0.3 secs)
vectors (1.7 secs)
unordered sets (1.9 secs)
sets (3 secs)

Here is the code:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <set>
#include <unordered_set>
#include <vector>

int main() {
    using std::cout, std::endl, std::set, std::unordered_set, std::vector, std::find;
    
    int i;
    
    const long ITERATIONS = 10000000;
    
    int a[] {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15};
    for (int i = 0; i < ITERATIONS; i++) {
        if (find(a, a + 16, rand() % 64) == a + 16) {}
        else {}
    }
    
    vector<int> v{0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15};
    for (i = 0; i < ITERATIONS; i++) {
        if (find(v.begin(), v.end(), rand() % 64) == v.end()) {}
        else {}
    }
    
    set<int> s({0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15});
    for (i = 0; i < ITERATIONS; i++) {
        if (find(s.begin(), s.end(), rand() % 64) == s.end()) {}
        else {}
    }
    
    unordered_set<int> us({0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15});
    for (i = 0; i < ITERATIONS; i++) {
        if (find(us.begin(), us.end(), rand() % 64) == us.end()) {}
        else {}
    }
}
```

Comment: What optimization level did you run this code at, and how did you time these results? I'd also point out that 16 elements is a pretty small container.

Comment: Searching between 16 integers? That's one cache line, no wonder that linear search through an array is the fastest. Try 16 million integers, you will see much different results. Of course if 16 ints is your use case, go for it.

Comment: I don't need a large container for this project, 16 is about the most numbers used

Comment: the difference between `O(N)` and `O(logN)` matters for large N. All containers but arrays introduce overhead hence for N=16 that overhead can outweigh the difference in asymptotic complexity by far

Comment: Okay, still `std::vector` should be with optimizations as fast as the raw array or `std::array`.

Comment: `std::find()` instead of `std::unordered_map::find()` makes no sense.

Comment: @BanjoMan -- First, you didn't mention whether you are running a "debug", unoptimized build, or an "release", optimized build.  If it's an unoptimized build, your timing information is worthless.  Second, 16 items is almost nothing.  When you *do* actually use a million elements, then test things.  Heck, even bubble-sorting 16 elements maybe faster than quicksort, just to show how 16 elements is not worthy of testing.

Comment: rather try 16 iterations with 10000000 elements ;)

Comment: There is zero need for `else {}`. If you have no `else` logic, you just don't include the block at all. Finally, I don't see how you're getting the timings. At all.

Comment: @BanjoMan The other glaring thing missing from your code is -- there is no timing code, i.e. no calls to start and stop a timer anywhere.  Thus we have no idea where you are getting your numbers from.  All of this information, how you are timing, and the optimization settings used to build the application, is missing from your post.

Comment: @BanjoMan -- Think of it this way: with 16 elements as a test, that is equivalent to timing a high-school athlete and Usain Bolt in the 100 meters dash, and only looking at the first step each takes to determine who is faster.

Comment: The traditional or C array can be directly accessed.  The address of an element can be calculated, then accessed.  A vector may need to access a function to get to the element; this may cause the instruction cache to be cleared.  The `set` and `unordered` set require a more complex access function and cannot be accessed directly.  These performance issues are known at the data structure (design) level.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Please remember that in `C` and `C++` there is the [as if rule](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/as_if)!
This means compiler can transform code by any means (even by dropping code) as long as observable result of running code remains unchanged.

Here is [godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/3zhdd74Tb) of your code.

Now note what compiler did for `if (find(a, a + 16, rand() % 64) == a + 16) {}`:

```cpp
.L206:
        call    rand
        sub     ebx, 1
        jne     .L206
```

Basically compiler noticed that result of it is not used and remove everything expect calling `rand()` which has side effects (visible changes in results).

The same happen for `std::vector`:

```
.L207:
        call    rand
        sub     ebx, 1
        jne     .L207
```

And even for `std::set` and `std::unordered_set` compiler was able to perform same optimization. The difference you are seeing (you didn't specified how you did that) is just result of initializing all of this variables which is time consuming for more complex containers.

Writing good performance test is hard and should be approached with caution.

There is also second problem with your question. Time complexity of given code.
Searching array and searching `std::set` and `std::unrodered_set` scales differently to size of data. For small data set simple array will be fates since its simple implementation and optimal access to memory. As data size grow time complexity of `std::find` for array will grow as `O(n)` on other hand slower `std::set` time to find item will grow as `O(log n)` and for `std::unordered_set` it will be constant time `O(1)`. So for small amount of data array will be fastest, for medium size `std::set` is the winner and if amount of data will be large `std::unordered_set` will be best.

Take a look on [this benchmark example](https://quick-bench.com/q/WdS5iLQL0N4hVh6jXpW_c9csA50) which uses google benchmark.

Answer (score 1):

You are not measuring efficiency, you are measuring performance. And doing so badly.

The effect of address space randomization or just different usernames or other variable in `env` has up to about 40% effect on speed. That's more than the difference between -O0 and -O2. You are only measuring one single system with one single address space layout 10000000 times. That makes the value about meaningless.

And yet you still manage to figure out that for 16 ints any attempt to be better than just looking at all of them will perform worse. A simple linear search in a single cache line (or two if the layout is bad, more likely) is just simply the best way.

Now try again with 10000000 ints and run the binary 1000 times. Even better if you use a layout randomizer to truly exclude accidents of the layout from the timing.

Note: Iirc the limit for sort where an array with bubble sort is best is somewhere between 32 and 64 ints and find is even simpler.